# Is it possible to craft legendary items with special attributes?

Tags: diablo-iii

Like Fire Walkers' "Burn the ground…"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some legendaries have their own unique effect.  If it has that in the crafting window (like the [Reaper's Wraps](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/reapers-wraps)), it will have those special effects.  But there's no way to create legendaries that have their own special effects outside of that.  You can't even re-roll them with the Mystic.

Comment: Yes, Reaper's Wraps is the only one craftable legendary I know that has a (crappy) special effects. Do you know any else? IMO, legendaries without special effects are not worth crafting.

Comment: Feel free to ask that, but be aware that questions that show no effort are frowned upon here.  I'd recommend doing some research on your own before asking.

Comment: There's a craftable Crusader 2h flail, Golden something, which has a special effect.

Comment: There is also a legendary crusader shield that does something with slam or so

Comment: @an0 : reaper's wraps' unique affix is far from crappy. For certain classes it has little impact but for a Crusader or DH, it has a big influence in fight sustainability. Of course, there can always be a better substitute, but depend on how you play and what build you have.

Comment: @an0 a lot of the legendary sets provide quite good effects (not necessary special procs though), such as aughilds, captain crimsons, borns...

Comment: I can't quote the exact items, but I have approx. two legendary recipes (not reaper's wraps; out of a large number) that have unique effects listed.